# How to get real time updates for a facebook group's feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to write a script which will read from one of my Facebook group's feeds.

Currently Facebook's Real time subscriptions using the dashboard seem to be available only for 'user', 'page' and 'payments' objects. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/#subscribingviaappdash)

Also when I try to get my current subscriptions using a GET request in the Graph API Explorer

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/subscriptions?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

I get the following error even though I am using the app's access token in the request:

```
{
  "error": {
  "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.", 
  "type": "OAuthException", 
  "code": 15
  }
}
```

How do I proceed?

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message? Are you using an app access token?

Comment: Yes. I am using the App's Access Token generated via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/.

Comment: Ensure that you are using the correct token - try to [debug it](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) or make a different call to the API using that token. You should not get this error if the token is valid.